# drupal path alias exist or not

Tags: drupal

How to find whether url is *exist or not* ? i.e url that leads to **'page not found'** error . for ex: finding test/testpage is exist or not

i mean that to check whether given relative path or full path is really exist on the site or it leads to page not found error

Comment: Don't know about anybody else, but I can't understand your question. Can you rephrase it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [menu_valid_path](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/menu_valid_path/6)() function for this.  This returns TRUE or FALSE based on 1. Whether the menu path exists and 2. if the current user has permission to view the item.

You call it like this:

```
$item_exists = menu_valid_path(array('link_path' => $some_path));
```

Where $some_path is the path you want to test.

Comment: drupal_valid_path in D7

Answer (score 4):

If you want to know does only an alias exist or not, use:

```
$path_exist = drupal_lookup_path('alias',$path);
```

But if you want to know does one of system path or alias is exist, use:

```
$path_exist = drupal_lookup_path('alias',$path) || drupal_lookup_path('source',$path);
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Drupal 8.8, Path Alias is a content entity.
So we can use

```
$pathStorage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('path_alias');
$aliases = $pathStorage->loadByProperties(['alias' => $alias]);
// or 
// $pathStorage->loadByProperties(['path' => $path]);
$existingAlias = count($aliases) > 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Refer to [this URL](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Path%21AliasStorageInterface.php/interface/AliasStorageInterface/8.2.x) for Drupal 8.

You can use:

```
\Drupal::service('path.alias_storage')->aliasExists('current_path', 'en')
```

And it will load "**1**" if alias exists in system.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use requesting page: http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_http_request/6 
On error you will get not empty $result->error.

Answer (score 1):

For **Drupal 9** `\Drupal::service('path.alias_storage')->aliasExists()` is not longer available.

But you can use:

```
    $path_alias_repository = \Drupal::service('path_alias.repository');
    if ($path_alias_repository->lookupByAlias($alias, 'en')) {
        return TRUE;
    }
```

Solution is taken from [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/308477).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31405924)